# Get wrong CPU usage data for Azure App Service Plan through REST API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

We have an Azure App Service Plan running a Web Job, I can see the CPU percentage used in the Azure portal when I look at the Service Plan, and I want to get this information from the REST API. I can get the information, however I don't know what I'm doing wrong as the information I get doesn't match up with what the portal shows.

Here's the URL I'm getting:

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{MySubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/My-Resouce-Group/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/My-App-Service-Plan/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?$filter=name.value%20eq%20'CpuPercentage'%20and%20(aggregationType%20eq%20'None'%20or%20aggregationType%20eq%20'Average'%20or%20aggregationType%20eq%20'Minimum'%20or%20aggregationType%20eq%20'Maximum'%20or%20aggregationType%20eq%20'Total'%20or%20aggregationType%20eq%20'Count')%20and%20startTime%20eq%202017-10-03T08:55:00Z%20and%20endTime%20eq%202017-10-03T09:00:00Z&api-version=2016-09-01

At 8:55 the portal shows just under 20% CPU usage, however what I get back from the REST API at this time is this:

"total":1.0,"count":1.0,"average":1.0,"minimum":1.0,"maximum":1.0

What do I need to do to get the data that is shown in the portal?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I have create a test demo on my side, it works well.

The result is the same.

I guess may be something wrong with your filter parameters.

I suggest you could try my url and test again.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription}/resourceGroups/{name}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/{name}/providers/microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2016-09-01&$filter=(name.value%20eq%20'CpuPercentage')%20and%20(aggregationType%20eq%20'Average'%20or%20aggregationType%20eq%20'Minimum')%20and%20startTime%20eq%202017-10-04T01:26:41.812Z%20and%20endTime%20eq%202017-10-04T02:26:41.812Z%20and%20timeGrain%20eq%20duration'PT1M'
```

Result:

[image]

Besides, you could also get the filter directly from azure portal.

You could use browser F12 to check the request details from azure monitor.

Details, you could refer to this image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to do this Brando and posting the thorough reply. I hoped someone familiar with this might spot something I was doing wrong, or reproduce the problem, but you've given me some things to look at so I'll check again. Thanks.